# SCSS Files in Angular 7

Tags: angular, sass

I'm trying to import a SCSS file in a CSS file. The following error appears when I try to compile the project. Has somebody faced this issue? I've looked in internet, but the error explanation is not that clear. Thanks!

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.css (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\src\theme.scss'
```

**styles.css**

```
@import "/src/theme.scss";
```

Comment: The file `theme.scss` in `src` exists?

Comment: check the import path.. it should be a relative path , starting from `'./'` or `../`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add it to the angular.json file like so:

```
    styles: [
  "src/theme.scss"
            ]
```

and it should pick it up.